# How to find Business Unit Related to the Sales Order in tables?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have a requirement, where I need to create a form to display sales order details along with Business Unit. I tried all the tables, but not able to figure out how can I get Business Unit for that Sales Id. Can some one please help?

I have salesId, but I am not able to find the related Business Unit defined on the sales order form.

Path for Business Unit: Line Details > Default Financial Dimensions > Business Unit.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show on your form standard financial dimension control like that
[image]

then you can follow this step by step guide [How add financial dimension on forms inside Ax2012](http://mukesh-ax.blogspot.com.by/2012/09/how-add-financial-dimension-on-forms.html)

Just skip first point because `SalesTable` already has `DefaultDimension` field.

But if you need to find record in *General ledger > Setup > Organization > Business units* then you can use this piece of code

```
DimensionAttributeValueSetStorage    dimStorage;    
DimensionValue                       dimensionValue;
DimensionDefault                     defaultDimension;
int                                  i;
;

defaultDimension = SalesTable.DefaultDimension; 
dimStorage = DimensionAttributeValueSetStorage::find(defaultDimension);

for (i = 1; i <= dimStorage.elements(); i++)
{
    if (DimensionAttribute::find(dimStorage.getAttributeByIndex(i)).Name == 'BusinessUnit')
    {
        dimensionValue = dimStorage.getDisplayValueByIndex(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

`dimensionValue` holds `Operation unit number` and using this value you can find record in Business units (`OMOperatingUnit`) table.